# Angular tries to use/access a function (assigned to this) which hasn't been used within directive's return object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is the exact directive I am using:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('App')
  .directive('aView', function ($stateParams) {

    this.link = function(scope, template, directiveAttrs){
      template.addClass(scope.elem.classes);
    }

    return {
      template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {elem: '='},
      compile: function(template){
        return function(scope, template, directiveAttrs){
          template.addClass(scope.elem.classes);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

This gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'link' of undefined
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/directives/aView.js:5:15
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2990:25)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3894:43
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:130:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3892:13)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3000:28)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2838:37
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2960:39)
    at addDirective (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4609:51)
```

The weird thing about this one is that nowhere within the returned configuration object of this directive do I reference the this.link() function. Also why am I getting undefined? My directive is almost exact copy of agghead's lesson 25.

Now, if I comment out this.link() function, a set of errors appears:

```
10 x :
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new ngDirective.controller (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14357:5)
    at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3000:28)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3012:23)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4981:24
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4560:17
    at forEach (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:137:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4545:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4191:15)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4194:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4096:30) angular.js:5930
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [a lot of code here]...
...debug.watchPerf[watchStr].calls += 1;\n                return ret;\n              }; newVal: undefined; oldVal: undefined"]]
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8126:19)
    at Object.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
    at Object.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8304:24)
    at Object.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9669:36
    at completeOutstandingRequest (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3139:10)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3433:7
```

What is going on? Has there mysteriously a dependency on my this.link function appeared within angular?
 
**BTW**, it does not matter what this function is named, errors still appear with a different name as reference.
**BTW2**, My stack is: yeoman (Grunt as the local server), angular.js, angular.ui.bootstrap, angular.ui.router, Firebase, angularFire. Project is made with yo angular generator.
**BTW3**, before I started to tinker with this directive, the one originally generated with yo angular:directive had a *link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs)* if this matters.
Appreciate you time,
Jared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in a directive the `this` is `window`, but because you are using strict mode it is changed to `undefined`. This is to stop people accidentally modifying the global object when using the constructor pattern without using the `new` keyword.

If you remove the `"use strict";` you will see no errors, but if you `console.log(this)` you will see window, which you shouldn't be adding methods to like that anyway. I suggest you just do

```
var link = function() { ... };
```

Comment: It worked, cheers. But why would the other set of errors appear when I comment out the function?

Comment: Maybe you need to rename one of the `template` you shouldn't have them both named the same,

Comment: Yeah, I renamed the 'element' to 'template', because I was always getting confused about which 'element' it was referring to. I've been using this name in several places, and haven't had any problem with it, but I will change it to something like templateElem, just to be sure :).